# Non pinhole camera

Tags: camera

I'm trying to figure out something about this paper,  Non-Pinhole Approximations for Interactive Rendering.

It's a really interesting paper but I can't really understand the way translate into m own game engine.

So from what I understood to create a single non pinhole occlusion camera I need to project the image along different ray based on the depth value ? Or do I need to distort the vertex projection so I can see occluded part?

Also I'm not sure but can use something similar to a fisheye camera ?

Answer (score 0):

fisheye camera is simply a camera with large field of view (or relatively small focal length). It can have significant radial distortions that typically grow with the field of view. But otherwise it is the same as a regular pinhole camera.

I looked at the paper but still cannot understand your question.